# How do I append text to a file that might not exist in a folder structure that also might not exist?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a simple, lightweight log to txt system. I already have all logs redirected to a function that, at the moment, just does console.log but my console is flooded with various things and I want to spread them in error, warning and info txt files.

I would write them to a folder of the following form:

```
"logs/" + time.year + "-" + time.month + "-" + time.day + "/" + time.day + "/error.txt"
```

As you can see, I am keeping all logs for a particular day in a day folder, with the name as a complete date.
In it there will be one folder for each hour of that particular day, and in each of those folders, 3 files with warning, error and info (and perhaps something else, doesn't matter).

I would append text into those text files, but these cases come up:
The date folder might not exist;
The hour folder might not exist;
The txt file might not exist;

Using the append functions from the fs library throws some errors I don't understand and google search proves fruitless.

I really don't wanna use yet another complex library just for this 1 small thing, so I would appreciate a simple and clean solution.

Cheers!

Comment: think you could find this useful https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp

Comment: so I call the mkdirp and then appendfile?

Comment: yep, mkdirp('/tmp/foo/bar/baz', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err)
    yourFileCreatorWriter(data)
});

Comment: np, glad this helped you